# What are the tax treaties between USA and India which I can mention in 1040 NR-EZ Item J?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, f1-student-visa, form-1040x

I worked on-campus in 2015 for 2 months during my masters in IT on F-1 Visa as a student. My school paid me around 1500$ for working 2 months on-campus.

Then I got an internship in my final semister and started working for a company. I have earned some income around 3000$.

Now, I graduated from my school in May, 2015. I started working with the same company for a co-op position and I have earned an income around 15000$ after graduating, during my OPT.

I am filing taxes. these are the forms which I am considering, please let me know If I am goind wrong.

1. 8843
2. 1040 NR-EZ
3. State from which is Form-1 NR/PY in Massachusetts

I have filled all these forms and I am stuck with the Item J in the 1040 NR-EZ, which is about the India-USA tax treaties. In this item J, I have to mentioned about the standardized deduction for students like US-India tax treaty accroding to according to article 21(2). I want to know if there are any other tax treaties for International students from India, who are in F-1?

Are there any other exemptions for an international student from India, please let me know If I missed something? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There's only one tax treaty ([the Indo-US tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/International-Businesses/India---Tax-Treaty-Documents)). You need to check what else may apply to you (probably nothing else, but you need to check based on your personal circumstances).